# How to traverse in a single activity with different type of lists and on click back button should return me the previous list

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask

I have an app which needs to display number of lists (it will be determined on runtime) On clicking the listview item I need to display the lists.

Example:

I need to display the list of documents & folders based on API calls.
If it is a document I should be able to view the document.
If it is a Folder, it should display the files present in that folder.

There is no restriction on the number of folders. So you can think of it like nested folders. Every time the user clicks on a folder I am displaying the documents and folders (if any) inside that.
What all I can do is, I am able to display the list but it is overriding the previous list. I want to preserve the previous lists since when the user clicks on back button, I need to display the previous list.

**Example: folder1 -> folder2 -> folder3 ... suppose that I am in folder3 view and if the user clicks back button, I need the display the contents of folder2.**

**I cannot create multiple classes since I don't know that how many nested folders are there ( By the way, I am getting the data from Rest API calls and I am using ASYNC Tasks).**

Comment: Put the folder to display for example in the intent data like https://stackoverflow.com/a/2091482/995891 - multiple classes are for different behavior, not different state like a folder

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.. sorry.. I didnt get that piece of code. I knew about intents and passing parameters between those 2 activities. But how would it helps me? Do I need to create another activity to do that? If possible, Can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: Why don't you reload the list when you click the back button the same way you loaded it when you visited it for the first time?

Comment: Doesn't need to be a new activity, can also be done with a new Fragment on the backstack for each level of navigation, https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal#back-fragments and https://stackoverflow.com/a/9245510/995891 for folder parameter